# makefile do same job in a lot of folders

Tags: web, makefile, gnu-make

I try to build a static website via `make`.

I would like to compress all images inside sub-directories of `src` folder, leaving `src` untouched, then output compressed images to `build` folder via `make`.

```
src
  + img/
      + thumb/
           + a.jpg
           + x.png
      + big/
           + p.jpg
           + q.jpg
      + ...
build
  + img/
      + thumb/
           + a.jpg
           + x.png
      + big/
           + p.jpg
           + q.jpg
      + ...
```

I don't want to write some like this:

```
build/img/thumb/%: src/img/thumb/%
    mkdir....
    compress $<
build/img/big/%: src/img/big/%
    mkdir....
    compress $<
...
```

since all images inside `src` do same jobs, is there any possible to write more concise code?

something like this:

```
build/%: src/%
    mkdir....
    compress $<
```

---

#### update 1

```
build/img/%: src/img/%
    mkdir....
    compress $<
```

this snippet show error:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

#### update 2

after some google, I add `all: build/img/*/*.jpg`:

```
all: build/img/*/*.jpg

# this line only specified how to create your targets, but not which.
build/img/%: src/img/%
    jpegoptim --strip-all $<
```

this version only dealt one file (first file?)...

ref: [wildcard](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_tutorial.html#Using%20Wildcards)

---

#### update 3

I find `make` would stuck the filename with space...

my version:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-msys
```

Comment: You can use a foreach loop to generate the per-directory rules or you could have a rule per file-type both of which should work just fine. Your rule as-is should also work just fine but it will also apply to anything else under `src` and that may not be what you want.

Comment: Filenames with spaces are notoriously icky with Make.  I don't think there is a good solution to that.